# Combining two different data tables into one in R

Tags: r, datatable

I've got two data tables with the same structure and I'd like to combine them into one.
I've read about the merge function, but as I've understood, that'd try to merge by common values, so I don't know if that's what I'm looking for.
It'd be something like this:

[image]

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: Not sure, what excactly you are looking for. `merge()` seems to be a good fit. Or have a look at `rbindlist()` to combine and `unique()` for deduplicating afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the rbind() function.

```
new_data <- rbind(data1, data2)
```

Hope this helps.